# VBA Cells as Keys in Dictionary

Tags: excel, dictionary, key, vba

I wrote a function that would builds a dictionary with Key => Value pairs from an Excel sheet. This works fine so far but I figured out that my dictinary can have duplicated keys, when cells have the same value.

Can anyone explain me this behavior?

```
Function CreateDictionaryBySheet( _
SheetName As String, _
Optional KeyColumn As Long = 1, _
Optional ValueColumn As Long = 2, _
Optional StartRow As Long = 2 _
) As Object

Dim MyDictionary As Object
Set MyDictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Worksheets(SheetName).Activate

Dim MaxRows As Long
MaxRows = GetNumberOfRows(SheetName, KeyColumn)

Dim Row As Long
For Row = StartRow To MaxRows

    MyDictionary.Item(Cells(Row, KeyColumn)) = Cells(Row, ValueColumn)

Next Row

Set CreateDictionaryBySheet = MyDictionary

End Function
```

I wrote this Loop to check my Code:

```
Sub Test()

Dim Key As Variant
Dim MyDictionary As Object
Set MyDictionary = CreateDictionaryBySheet("Config")

For Each Key In MyDictionary

MsgBox (Key & " => " & MyDictionary(Key))

Next Key

End Sub
```

Assuming that cells(2,1) and cells(3,1) both are "a" and cells(2,2) = 1 and cells(3,2) = 2 I will see two msgboxes: one with "a => 1" and one with "a => 2"

This seems odd to me because I did assume to see just one msgbox namely "a => 2"

Thanks for your help!
Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I just figured out that I get the assumed behavior when reffering to cell values instead:

This will allow duplicated values:

```
    MyDictionary.Item(Cells(Row, KeyColumn)) = Cells(Row, ValueColumn)
```

This not:

```
    MyDictionary.Item(Cells(Row, KeyColumn).Value) = Cells(Row, ValueColumn).Value
```

I guess this is because dictinary did take the Cells-Object as a key in the first case which was not intended.